# Delta hedging cost of exotic options?

Tags: option-pricing, delta-hedging

I'm simulating dynamic delta hedging for up-and-out call option.
For plain vanilla call options, I heard that the option price is the expected value of the accumulated delta hedging cost. Does it also hold for exotic option, like up-and-out call options?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you use the BS Model for computing deltas and the same model for evolving the stock price then you should replicate the pay-off of any contract.

Comment: Is it always possible to delta-hedge an exotic option in BS?

Comment: yes -- every pay-off is replicable.